# Is there a way not to print out the else statement when inputting a valid number?

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

This is the problem that I need to code in C++
[The question/problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT6BY.png)

I can't seem to know the problem of my code.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    cout << "Total Purchase Cost: Php ";
    double total;
    cin >> total;
    
    cout << "Loyalty Card Type: ";
    int cardType;
    cin >> cardType;
    double discount = 0;
    double type1 = 0.10;
    double type2 = 0;
    double type3 = 0.15;
    if (cardType == 1)
        discount = total * type1;
    if (cardType == 2)
        discount = total * type2;
    if (cardType == 3)
        discount = total * type3;
    else 
    cout << "Invalid Card";
    cout << "Discounted Cost: Php \n" << discount;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run it, the discount price is correct and the computations is right and the output text "Discounted Cost: Php ---" seems to be working perfeclty. But when I started to add an else statement so that when I input an invalid number to my if statement, it will output a "Invalid Card" message. But when I input a valid number, the else statement still prints out even if it shouldn't be.

Comment: Use the scope, Luke, use the scope.

Comment: Do you realize that your `else` is only attached to the last `if`? Do you also realize that the `if` statements are all run independently? You want to use if/else if/else, or a switch. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: It's going to work much better if you upload all pictures and images to Facebook or Twitter, instead, those web sites are designed for that. On Stackoverflow it'll work much better if all relevant information gets included in the question ***as plain text***, so that anyone can cut/paste the shown code and try it themselves. Can you remove all images and photos from your questions, and include the same information as plain text?

Answer (score 2):

To solve your immediate problem, I suggest that you replace all `if` statements except the first one with `else if`:

```
if (cardType == 1)
    discount = total * type1;
else if (cardType == 2)
    discount = total * type2;
else if (cardType == 3)
    discount = total * type3;
else
    cout << "Invalid Card" << '\n';
cout << "Discounted Cost: Php \n" << discount << '\n';
```

However, the logic above still has the problem that the line

```
cout << "Discounted Cost: Php \n" << discount;
```

will be printed even if the card is invalid, which you probably do not want. For this reason, it would be probabably better to add a variable `bool valid` and to only print `"Discounted Cost"` if that variable is `true`:

```
bool valid = false;

if (cardType == 1)
{
    discount = total * type1;
    valid = true;
}
else if (cardType == 2)
{
    discount = total * type2;
    valid = true;
}
else if (cardType == 3)
{
    discount = total * type3;
    valid = true;
}
else
{
    cout << "Invalid Card" << '\n';
}

if ( valid )
{
    cout << "Discounted Cost: Php \n" << discount << '\n';
}
```

Instead of using a chain of `if`...`else if` statements, you can also use a [`switch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) statement:

```
bool valid = false;

switch ( cardType )
{
    case 1:
        discount = total * type1;
        valid = true;
        break;
    case 2:
        discount = total * type2;
        valid = true;
        break;
    case 3:
        discount = total * type3;
        valid = true;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid Card" << '\n';
}

if ( valid )
{
    cout << "Discounted Cost: Php \n" << discount << '\n';
}
```

This logic could be simplified a bit by using a pointer instead, which can be set to `nullptr` to indicate that the card is invalid.

```
double *type = nullptr;

switch ( cardType )
{
    case 1:
        type = &type1;
        break;
    case 2:
        type = &type2;
        break;
    case 3:
        type = &type3;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid Card" << '\n';
}

if ( type != nullptr )
    cout << "Discounted Cost: Php \n" << total * *type << '\n';
}
```

However, an even simpler way of writing the whole program would be:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Total Purchase Cost: Php ";
    double total;
    cin >> total;
    
    cout << "Loyalty Card Type: ";
    int cardType;
    cin >> cardType;

    constexpr double types[3] = { 0.10, 0, 0.15 };
    
    if ( 1 <= cardType && cardType <= 3 )
    {
        cout << "Discounted Cost: Php \n" << total * types[cardType-1] << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid Card" << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Another issue in your code (and also in my code above) is that you seem to be calculating the discount, but you are printing this value out as the "Discounted cost". This is incorrect. The proper mathematical formula is:

```
discounted cost = full price - discount
```

To fix this, the line

```
constexpr double types[3] = { 0.10, 0, 0.15 };
```

should be changed to:

```
constexpr double types[3] = { 0.90, 1.00, 0.85 };
```